# Как получить длительность mp3 файла без скачивания всего файла

Tags: c#, mp3

Для изображений есть метод для определения размера картинки без полного скачивания. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111345/getting-image-dimensions-without-reading-the-entire-file

А вот как быть с mp3 файлами? Есть ли такое для таких файлов?

Comment: Насколько мне помнится, с CBR оценить время просто (длина / размер фрейма), а вот с VBR сложнее.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13722637/1991579

Comment: @VladD с VBR никак (:

Comment: Да и с CBR не всё так просто, т.к. в файл скорее всего еще зашиты теги, размер которых на глаз оценить нельзя

Comment: @elp87: Но по крайней мере стартовые теги (id3v1, кажется, идёт в начале), можно найти не загружая весь файл. А вот id3v2 может быть где угодно, и обычно находится в конце. (А ещё он может быть, в отличие от id3v1, как угодно большим.)

Comment: если файл на web-сервере, то размер файла можно узнать если послать http-запрос HEAD. зная размер и т.д. можно примерно понять длительность.

Answer (score 1):

Из-за возможного VBR и неясной длины тегов (особенно если там картинок понапихано) - в общем случае нельзя

Можно оценить примерно по размеру, битрейту нескольких первых фреймов(битрейт указывается в заголовке каждого фрейма, и по ним можно понять CBR там или порядок значения VBR) и надежде, что картинка если и есть - то небольшая.

Если удаленный сервер поддерживает, причем скоре всего да - слать Range-запросы(т.е. читать не целиком, а только начало), либо менее красиво - оборвать коннект, прочитав кусок.

В теории можно через range так же попробовать прочитать собственно и теги, но это уже несколько запросов на один файл - теги живут либо в начале, либо в конце файла